# (C#) How to transfer tokens

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet, coinbase

I am trying to transfer tokens from myEtherWallet and Codebase in C#.
I found a code sample https://github.com/maxpaynestory/Nethereum.ERC20.Token.Transfer.Sample/blob/master/EthereumClient.cs
and have this code:

```
var transactionMessage = new TransferFunction()
        {
            FromAddress = accountFrom,
            To = accountTo,
            AmountToSend = tokens
        };
var transferHandler = web.Eth.GetContractTransactionHandler<TransferFunction>();
Task<string> transactionHashTask = transferHandler.SendRequestAsync(transactionMessage, contractAddress);
return await transactionHashTask;
```

For the contract address I am using the contract address of the token(https://etherscan.io/address/0xb92c39977f18c25121a76748a6cc25c29584a12c).

I keep getting an error "gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction"
I changed the token amount to be a lot less then the account balance and I have enough ETH in the account to cover gas.

Comment: Other than the gas amount, the major reason for this error message, something been thrown from the contract code. Check the contract code and ensure you pass all that `require`

Comment: Can you please clarify by what you mean by contract code.

Comment: I mean the smart contract code (of the token) from what you are trying to consume the `transfer`

Comment: Can you please clarify further by what is the smart contract code. I am new to this.

Comment: The parameter that you are using `contractAddress` which is the smart-code developed and deployed on the blockchain. This will have a few functions in it for others to interact with it. When the validation fails in that smart contract code, it will throw the error as you received.